# Highlight selected header in preference-headers

Tags: android, settings, fragment

I'm using the new preference-headers to show the settings in my application.
While the standard settings activity on my Motorola Xoom shows the selected item in the header list with a blue background, my settingsactivity that extend PreferenceActivity does not highlight the selected item in any way.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No answer so far. Please let me know whether the question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It was enough to use:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest: it used to be ="9" previously.

If you switch to 11 you will we see many changes: the menu is on the top and not on the bottom, the application icon is shown on the top-left and the title font is bigger
To customize the highlight etc I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.SettingsActivity" parent="@android:style/Theme">

        <item name="android:listSelector">@color/green</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

In the AndroidManifest for the SettingsActivity I used:

```
              android:theme="@style/Theme.SettingsActivity"
```

After switching to minsdk=11 it works